# mod_expires - reset the header cache

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching, mod-expires

I've tried `mod_expires`, but I made the mistake of caching the whole content of the web (not only specific resources), so the problem is that when someone opens the site (even for the first time) they will see old content.

After I switched off the `mod_expires` (default value) the issue still exists. Even Google page insights still sees the old content. Only `CTRL + F5` can fix the problem, but this is not a solution. I can't figure out why the new visits are still seeing the old content?